# When does a sequence (or a series) of real-analytic functions converge to a real-analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

It is well known that a sequence (or a series) of holomorphic functions converging uniformly converges to a holomorphic function. I would like to know under what condition a sequence (or a series) or real-analytic functions converges to a real-analytic function. Are there any simple criteria?

In particular, I would like to know whether a series of real-analytic functions converging absolutely and uniformly converges to a real-analytic function. I read in the proof of Lemma 1.8 in ["Mock theta functions"](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/878) written by S. P. Zwegers "since R is the (infinite) sum of real-analytic functions, and the series converges absolutely and uniformly, it is real-analytic." But I cannot understand why that fact holds.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense. I guess, I was being very sloppy, there...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check the real-analyticity on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 4):

A uniform limit of real-analytic functions certainly need not be real-analytic. Any continuous function on $[a,b]$ is a uniform limit of polynomials (and is hence the sum of a uniformly and absolutely convergent series of polynomials).

I can't think of any "simple" criteria. Even uniform convergence of a sequence of functions together with uniform convergence of every derivative is not enough; consider the Poisson integral of a function in $C^\infty_c$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The counterexample of the continuous function on [a, b] is simple and interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in $\mathbb{C}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$. The reason is that uniform convergence preserves continuity, not differentiability and beyond.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I sometimes deal with real-analytic functions. I feel larger difficuty in dealing with real-analytic functions than with holomorphic functions.