# $\{ f \in RH^2 : f(\alpha )=0 \}$ is closed linear subspace

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

if $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}$ open unit discthen show that$A=\{ f  \in RH^2 : f(\alpha )=0 \}$ is closed linear subspace in $RH^2$ the space of all rational functions which are analytic in the closed unit disc.

I start with a converging sequence in $A$ and tried to prove the limit lives in $A$, but couldn't complete the proof.
Any idea!

Comment: Tried using the poisson kernel representation?

Comment: @SeanNemetz, what are these? I checked wikipedia, they look like infinite series, right?

Comment: Are you working with Hardy spaces? If so you could use the integral poisson kernel.

Comment: @SeanNemetz. No I am not working on Hardy spaces.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Which norm are you using for this space?

Comment: @SeanNemetz. Supremum norm or inner product.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870518/when-does-a-sequence-or-a-series-of-real-analytic-functions-converge-to-a-real

Comment: @SeanNemetz. Is this post answering my question??

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, as of right now a sup norm convergence is insufficient. Maybe a normal convergence would help, but then I believe this would be a simple.